# When selecting from joined tables in MySQL, do the join operations happen before the selection?

Tags: mysql, database, join

I realize this might be a somewhat silly question, but I am studying SQL and I'm having a hard time comprehending the idea of joining tables.

Here is an example query:

```
select name, title from instructor natural join teaches, course 
  where teaches.course_id = course.course_id;
```

The joining happens BEFORE the selection, right? So if I ever want generate a query out of attributes that exist in different tables, I can simply select the ones I want without having to specify that they are in different tables, because once they are joined, the select command works on that joined relation, not the two separate relations?

Comment: Your join query is not correct.

Comment: It is good practice to qualify the fields selected with their table names, and necessary for disambiguation if multiple tables have fields with the same name; at very least, it helps document where the data is coming from, so when a query is later inspected the person reviewing it doesn't have to look back and forth at the table definitions to understand the query. (Also, unless your table structures never ever change, using natural join can be inviting problems when an added timestamp unintentionally ends up altering your join conditions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of a JOIN like it creates a new virtual row, where all the columns from both joined tables are side-by-side.

Suppose you have tables:

```
mysql> create table A (c1 int, c2 int, c3 int);
mysql> create table B (c4 int, c5 int, c6 int);
mysql> insert into A values (1,2,3); 
mysql> insert into B values (4,5,6);
```

You can query `FROM A JOIN B ON ...condition...` and now your WHERE clause and SELECT clause apply to a set of rows that have six columns.

```
mysql> select * from a join b;
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| c1   | c2   | c3   | c4   | c5   | c6   |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |    6 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

So you can do things like:

```
WHERE c1 = 123 AND c4 = 456
```

And it tests each *joined* row, so you can reference any column from either table, as if they are on the same row. In fact, they *are* on the same row, in the joined result.

Likewise you can reference any of these columns in the SELECT-list.

```
SELECT c2, c6 FROM ...
```

What if a column exists with the same name in both tables? That's when you should qualify the column names with the `table.column` syntax so it's not ambiguous which one you mean.

PS: You should get into the habit of using JOIN syntax for all your tables. Don't use the old comma-style join syntax. Mixing the two syntax styles will give you unexpected problems, because of order of precedence. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html in the section where you find "JOIN has higher precedence than the comma operator (,)..."

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot.